# Regular expression for some url name

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I need a regular expression in javascript to match some specified url (e.g. facebook.com), like this:

`http://www.facebook.com ; 
https://www.facebook.com ;
www.facebook.com`

but not

`www.something.com/test/redirect?=www.facebook.com`

Any idea?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Specifically what you asked for:

```
^(http(s)?://)?www.facebook.com
```

This will match the same, with the addition of `http://facebook.com` and `https://facebook.com`:

```
^((http(s)?://(www.)?)|www.)facebook.com
```

Comment: You don't need to escape forward slashes in a regular expression, only backward slashes

Comment: @Patashu: it depends on how you specify the regexp. If it's a regular expression literal (it's most likely for javascript) - then you have to do so. So you're not entirely correct

Answer (score 0):

If any of the following regexes match, the rule is satisfied:

^http://www\.facebook\.com.*

^https://www\.facebook\.com.*

^www\.facebook\.com$

^www\.facebook\.com/.*

^ matches the start of the string, $ matches the end. So you can use this to force a match to be at a certain point in the string.

Comment: Lol, why not use `indexOf` then?

Comment: if you use indexOf, it will only tell you the position of the string. For my case, when i use www.facebook.com as an indexOf parameter of www.something.com/test/redirect?=www.facebook.com , it will return some number > -1. But www.something.com/test/redirect?=www.facebook.com is not what i wanted